Access Image Resource from content element
I added via TCA/overwrite/tt_content.php an additional background_image field
So in every tt_content Element a background image should be rendered if available.
in TypoScript-Setup I added this:
lib.contentElement {
    dataProcessing {
        370 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        370 {
            references.fieldName = background_image
            as = backgroundImage
        }
    }
}

in my fluid-teamplate I try this:
<f:if condition="{backgroundImage.0.uid}">
  <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
  <f:debug>{backgroundImage}</f:debug>
  <f:variable name="theBgImage">{f:uri.image(image:'{backgroundImage.0}')}</f:variable>
</f:if>

the debug {_all} is attached
backgroundImage is an image object (I guess). I Pass this tho f:uri.image(img:'{backgroundImage}')
the Error gives me
Folder "/tmd/hd2024/fileadmin/editor/Team/Arbeit.jpg/" does not exist.
mind the trailing / !
Why is the path interpreted as a folder?
I am using TYPO3 V11.
with V10 I relayed on v:media (working), but I want to replace vhs (too many changes).

FilesProcessor
FilesProcessor returns always a group/array of files (As its name also reveals through the plural ;-) ). However, it is also possible that the group only contains one element or is even empty.
Even if only a maximum of one image can come out here (limited via TCA), this image is in an array and must be read out via the array: {backgroundImage.0}
Uri.image ViewHelper <f:uri.image>
The ViewHelper expects a concrete Image Object/file in its image-attribute - not a filereference.
However, if we look at the debug output above, we see that the FilesProcessor returns an array of FileReferences. So {backgroundImage.0} is not a file.
The file of a filereference can be accessed via its originalFile property.
Conclusion:
<f:if condition="{backgroundImage.0}">
  {f:uri.image(image: backgroundImage.0.originalFile}
</f:if>


Your explanation sounds very good. {f:uri.image(image:'{backgroundImage.0.originalFile}')} gives the correct paarh bust after
<f:variable name="theBgImage">{f:uri.image(image:'{backgroundImage.0.originalFile}')}</f:variable> it fails again with the same error  ( trailing / ).  For the first I help myself with the hardcoded: fileadmin{backgroundImage.0.identifier} I will track the sourcecode down to see what happens hopefully on the WE... Thank you for your advice.

So, what are you doing with the after after putting it in the variable?

I expect a sting with the path, pass ir to inline background: url({$backgroundImage})-style
